# SQL, проблема с foreign key

Tags: php, sql, key

Моя проблема началась с того, что при добавлении комментариев, они добавлялись ко всем постам.

У меня есть две таблицы:

первая, под названием post, содержит колонки post_id, user_id, content и checked(это эдакая фишка, могут видеть написанный вами текст другие или нет).

и друга, под названием comments, содержит id_post, comment_id, content и user_name.

Как я понимаю, нужно было сделать эдакий запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE `comment` ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_post) REFERENCES `post`(post_id);
```

Но, в результате, в колонке id_post всё по нулях.

Очень прошу о помощи тех, кто это дочитал. Так же у меня в голове никак не укладывается понимание этих primary и foreign key, потому буду чрезвычайно благодарна за помощь.

Comment: Предложение наподобие `ADD CONSTRAINT 'fk1' FOREIGN KEY` добавляет лишь ограничение внешнего ключа. К какому посту, какой комментарий относится должно определяться при его добавлении. Наверняка при сохранении комментария где-нибудь `id`  поста "потерялся".

Comment: Если у Вас уже были данные в таблице `comments`, то после создания связи с таблицей `post` значения в колонке `id_post` сами не появятся. Для новых комментариев Вам надо будет указывать значение `post.post_id` для поля `commnets.id_post`. Собственно, это можно было (следовало) делать и без `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: @Streletz, я как раз ломаю голову над тем, как и откуда вытянуть этот id

Comment: У уже существующих такую информацию взять уже не откуда. У вновь добавляемых это должна определять программа, когда пользователь пишет коммент вам же известно для какого поста он это делает. Вот и передавайте на сервер id поста вместе с текстом коммента, когда пользователь нажимает "отправить"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте скрытое поле в блоке ввода комментария, типа:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>" name="post_id">
```

При добавлении комментария используйте:

```
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

$sql = `insert intro comment(id_post, content, date) values ('$post_id','$text','$date');`
```